# Metamask Chrome Extension Recovery of All Accounts

Tags: metamask

I have a seedphrase and a private key for my Metamask extension. I recently formatted my computer, so the metamask extension was erased. I installed it again using my seedphrase and it accessed with no problems.

However, the problem is that all the other accounts that I created in the extension during the use of it aren't there. So I can conclude that seedphrase and password work to restore only one ethereum account and not all the set used in the extension.

Am I wrong or missing something? After recovering my extension through the seedphrase and password I expected to have all back, not just the first account.

Tell me if I'm doing something wrong, or if there is a workaround for that. Because if not, that would mean that we should download the private key for each new account created in metamask or they won't be backed up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to create them again using add new account and the new accounts should be equals to the old ones u had

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what do you mean with equal, isn't new account generated randomly?

Comment: No they are not generated randomly. They are all related to the seedphrase, but metamask shows u at the start only the account at index 0

Comment: well that's true, but my problem is that every new account I created using metamask, I never got its privaate key. And it seems that the seedphrase only works for the first account created.